# PHP with socket.io or recreate everything in node.js and socket.io?

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I'm currently planning on coding a private project, to be more specific a virtual chat room, where avatars can walk around chat.

Now I'm literally a little confused, which language should be used to code it in. For now I've used PHP for the backend things, such as authentification and HTML for the frontend.

But i know i will need to use Javascript, to draw the chatroom assets to a canvas element. And i will need to use socket.io (node.js) for the chat and the packets.

Now my question, can I even use PHP in the backend and use socket.io for the communication between the server and the client and the chat itself?

For now the process is the following:

1. User logs into a account, the background check is done in php
2. User gets redirected to a Dashboard
3. User selects the menu point world
4. User selects a chat world and gets redirected to another site which contains a canvas and a chatbox

Screenshot of step 3: [Select world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuK5K.png)

Screenshot of step 4: [Canvas with chatbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72f8Q.png)

How could I create a socket after building the canvas to use socket io to communicate with the server and to create the chat application?

Would it be easier to code the whole site without PHP and just using node.js and socket.io (Also for the user autentification etc) ?

I appreciate any kind of suggestions and help

Answer (score 1):

hmmm I assume you have good PHP skills but rather new to nodejs/socketio.

Yes nodejs can be better in real-time but it's rather for achieving scalability and it has its ecosystem, if you don't need either you can do it in PHP too.However, you can have both php and nodejs and that's perfeclty sane.

It will probably go like this : php for http requests and nodejs/socket.io for websockets connections, this setup will work if you don't need to call php from nodejs nor vice-versa(but both can still access the same database).

Now if you need to call either from either there are ways including message queues(like RabbitMQ) or exposing an HTTP API from one or either of them.

As for coding the whole thing in nodejs I wouldn't do that, php is pretty good at the tasks you mentioned, I still think that using nodejs for chats is going to be better .

Now you mentioned that it's private, in the future team members matter.

If this project is for learning purposes I do think that nodejs skills would be good to have under belt whether you need its scalability and/or ecosystem or not.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your response! As you already asumed im rather new to nodejs/socketio. And worked in multiple projects which used php and c#. So yea, ill probably use the way you mentioned to use PHP for the http requests and nodejs/socket.io for websockets connections. So i could do the auth part using PHP as it already does and create the socket authentification using the user object after authentificating :)